# paperclip save file without write access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, nginx, paperclip, passenger

I notice that paperclip doesn't make thumb and other style images, and if I `bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=development paperclip:refresh:thumbnails CLASS=ListingImage`

I get

```
Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/deploy/sharetribeProd/sharetribe/public/system/images/34/original/93.png - skipping file.
```

Here is mine dir listings.

```
deploy@linestudio:~/sharetribeProd/sharetribe$ ls -la public/system/images/33
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Dec 26 08:50 .
drwxrwxrwx 5 www-data www-data 4096 Dec 26 08:53 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Dec 26 08:50 original
deploy@linestudio:~/sharetribeProd/sharetribe$ ls -la public/system/images/33/original/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Dec 26 08:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Dec 26 08:50 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 2340 Dec 26 08:50 93.png
```

I am not sure, what info I have to show more - help please. It is first time I see that error, looks like paperclip saves images without +w rules and then just cant get it for resize. I am close to remove whole droplet and install server again. Thanks for attention.
P.S. Im using passenger + nginx.

Comment: It seems a problem with the user that runs rake. You could try: `sudo -u www-data bundle exec rake ...`

Comment: @Mat hey, thanks for attention - It isnt trouble with user - because file created, and created from www-data, but it created with -rw-r--r--  rules. If I manually change file permission to chmod +w, and then run rake paperclip:refresh - it works ok and create all styles

Comment: ok but if you run rails s, than do a file upload, the application user is www-data. If you run bundle exec rake (or anything else from command line) you are using your user, not www-data - that's probably why you are having permissions problems

Comment: @Mat it is on ubuntu server in DO. And the main problem - paperclip doesnt resize photo - it stores ONLY original, and doesnt create thumb and other from my style. And in log I can check, that it gaves me Permission denied. Because file's permission is -rw-r--r--

Comment: @Mat And if I change permission to 0777 - it works perfectly (and i dont change file's owner - only chmod)